# piping files betwen partitions nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, filesystems, fs

I'm trying to move a file from my `/tmp` folder to my home with node and `fs` module. I try the rename method but mi `tmp` partition is separated from `home` so I read in https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/2703 thats my problem was with partitions so I move to from renamme to pipe method, but when I try to move files, with some folders in it I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, open '/tmp/torrentPlayer/2f9505e50a48838c7f769c707ed9e29cee2f03ba'
    at Error (native)
```

I make the subdirectories tree before of this, but doesn't work and I don't know what Im doing wrong.

## EDIT

My code is:

```
var originalPath = "/tmp/originalFolder";
var savePath = "~/someFolder"

const fs = require('fs');
const mv = require('mv');
fs.readdir(originalPath, (err, files) => {
files.forEach(function (file){
    var source = fs.createReadStream(originalPath+ '/'+file);
    var newFile = fs.createWriteStream(savePath+'/'+file);
    //      console.log(+'\n'+newFile);

    source.pipe(newFile);
    source.on('end', function() { console.log(newFile); });
    source.on('error', function() { console.log("err"); });
})
})
```

But file may be a directory contains other directories.

Comment: We would need the see your code (pasted into your question) to see where you are going wrong.  The error message makes it sound like you're trying to create or open a directory instead of a file, but we need to see the code to know for sure and to know what to suggest.

Comment: see edit @jfriend00

Comment: If your `originalPath` contains sub-directories, then you will be trying to do createReadStream on a directory entry which will fail.  You would need to filter out sub-directories from `fs.readdir()` so you are only copying files.

Comment: okay i get this, but if I want to copy directories, how I do this?? @jfriend00

Comment: You detect sub-directories and call your function recursively, making sure you create the sub-directory on the target.

Comment: And I create the directories con other methos, right? @jfriend00

Comment: [fs.mkdir()](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdir_path_mode_callback)

Comment: I will try now, thanks so much @jfriend00

Comment: @jfriend00 I made this function to call it recursively but I can't find a way to make it work correctly.

```function moveFiles(source, dest){
   fs.readdir(source, (err, files) => {
  files.forEach( function(file){
      if(console.log(fs.lstatSync(file).isDirectory())){
    fs.mkdir(dest+'/'+file);
    moveFiles(source+'/'+file, dest+'/'+file);
      }else{
    console.log(savePath+ '/'+file);
      }
  })
    })
}```

Comment: Multi-line code in comments is not readable.  Use the edit button to add code to your question, properly format it and then you can post a comment indicating what you have added in your question.  For starters, `fs.mkdir()` is async.  You cannot ignore the callback it expects as an argument.

Comment: @jfriend00 sorry but I can't edit my comment, but I already have a good solution using the fs-extra module. Thanks for your amazong help.

Comment: You don't edit your comment.  You edit your question.  Multiline code belongs in your question where it can be properly formatted.